# Run Two Action At The Same Time Inside ONE Sequence

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sequence, skaction

I'm not sure if what I'm seeking is possible, but I'm just checking to make sure I'm not doing thing the hard way.

At the moment I have two sequences, which both run at the same time. Each sequence starts off by waiting 3 seconds and then one sequence scales a node, where the other adjusts that node's alpha. So the code looks something like this:

```
node.runAction(SKAction.sequence([animationWait, animationScale]))
node.runAction(SKAction.sequence([animationWait, animationAlpha]))
```

But is there a way of running both the animationScale and animationAlpha at the same time inside one sequence? So it will look something like this (this doesn't work, but I'm hoping you can see what I'm trying to do):

```
node.runAction(SKAction.sequence([animationWait, (animationScale, animationAlpha)]))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can group actions together to a sequence:

```
var actions = Array<SKAction>()

actions.append(SKAction.sequence([animationWait, animationScale]))
actions.append(SKAction.sequence([animationWait, animationAlpha]))

let group = SKAction.group(actions)

node.runAction(group)
```

> When the action executes, the actions that comprise the group all start immediately and run in parallel. The duration of the group action is the longest duration among the collection of actions. If an action in the group has a duration less than the group’s duration, the action completes, then idles until the group completes the remaining actions. This matters most when creating a repeating action that repeats a group.

Comment: Thanks for your answer evil, but I think I solved my own problem. However, what you have provided will help me out in another area of my code. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I just tested something out, and it seemed to have worked. Instead of the below:

```
node.runAction(SKAction.sequence([animationWait, (animationScale, animationAlpha)]))
```

do:

```
node.runAction(SKAction.sequence([animationWait, [animationScale, animationAlpha]]))
```

I'm surprised it worked. I was going to delete the question, but someone might find this handy.

EDIT:

The below no longer works

```
node.runAction(SKAction.sequence([animationWait, [animationScale, animationAlpha]]))
```

As evilboxingdragonslayer suggested, you will need to use "group", see below:

```
node.runAction(SKAction.sequence([animationWait, group([animationScale, animationAlpha])]))
```

Comment: ... both examples are the same copy-pasted code. What was the solved answer? :S

Comment: @msqar, they are different, one is in ( ) which doesn't work and one is in [ ] which use to work. I've now marked evilboxingdragonslayer's asker as the correct answer, as the only way (that I can see) of making two action run simultaneously is by using "group" SKAction.group([action1, action2]). Ill update my answer.